# Documenting a class in doxygen in a .doc file. @property not working

Tags: objective-c, class, properties, documentation, doxygen

Im documenting a ManagedObject class generated from the model outside the file where it is declared. Since this classe is autogenerated i dont want to modify the source code, then i have the documentation outside the .m file.

I have this atm:

```
/*!
    \file AA.h 
    \class AA
    \extends ManagedObject
    Data model object generated from the model.

    \public
    \property NSString * hardwareId
    \brief Unique identifier of the device
*/
```

Im obtaining an output file that has the AA class, it shows the inheritance, but nothing about the property or the public tags is being shown.

Don´t know what i am doing wrong.

Any ideas? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The problem is that i need to add a "namespace" with the name of the class to the begining of each property name.

So, my final file its like:

AA.doc

```
/*! 
    \class AA
    This file contains the documentation of the data model object generated from the model.  
*/

/*! 
    \var NSString * AA::hardwareId
    \brief Unique identifier of the device
*/
```

I had no need to specify the file and the inheritance since doxygen automatically took it from the .h file without adding anything